# how can i open inline visualforce editor in ap5.salesforce.com

Tags: apex, visualforce

iam getting inline visualforce editor in ap4.salesforce.com. but its not coming
in ap5.salesforce.can anyone tell me the solution please...
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=visualforce+inline+edit+photos&tbm=isch&source=iu&pf=m&ictx=1&fir=5FgAZ9lwA7M__M%253A%252CwtePFI30p9Bm5M%252C_&usg=___1aQXrCpVIggYtI92XpBZtHYRTo%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt77Wlp7vXAhUFT48KHYHCC-MQ9QEIJzAA#imgrc=5FgAZ9lwA7M__M:
just like this image i need a inline editor in ap5.salesforce.com

Answer (score 0):

step1:

In your settings please check development mode.

```
    setup->myseetings->personal->advanceuserdetails->developementmode(it shouldbe true)
```

step2:

Go to your url, you have to do small change: 
try to create new page for testing purpose:

https://epeople8-dev-ed--c.ap7.visual.force.com/apex/newpage

Comment: its working.Thankyou so much